# Creating a file using python on different folder

Tags: python

I am working on a remote server, say IP: 192.128.0.3. On this server there are two folders: `cgi-bin` & `html`. My python code file is in `cgi-bin` which wants to make data.json file in `html/Rohith/` where Rohith folder is already exists. I use the following code

```
 jsonObj = json.dumps(main_func(s));
 fileobj = open("http://192.128.0.3/Rohith/data.json","w+");
 fileobj.write(jsonObj);
```

But it is not creating the file there although I can create on the same folder (cgi-bin) of my python script. Can anyone tell me why it is not creating the file in the given destination?

Comment: please remove ';' semi columns from each line it is not required in python

Comment: Remove `"http:"`

Comment: Yes it is optional but I like to put. @AmanJaiswal :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Just tried, didn't work.

Comment: please share the error you get

Comment: @Vinny It is not creating the file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be path issues; I suggest to use full path instead. Try the following:

```
import os

jsonObj = json.dumps(main_func(s));
path = '\\'.join(__file__.split('\\')[:-2])  # this will return the parent 
                                             # folder of cgi-bin on Windows
out_file = path + '/html/Ronhith/data.json'
fileobj = open(out_file, 'w+')  # w+ mode creates the file if its not exists
fileobj.write(jsonObj)
```

If it still not working, try changing the file mode to `a+` from `w+`

> **a+** Opens a file for both appending and reading. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append mode. **If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading and writing.**

Comment: Thanks. It works because it returns the local path unlike IP path.

Comment: @Rohit. you welcome, if you found my answer helpful please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Selecting your answer. But why you downvoted my question?

Comment: @Rohit. I haven't downvoted your question. When I do, I leave a comment to improve next questions asked by the user

Answer (score 1):

file.write does not create a directory First you have to create a directory then use file.write() for example

```
if not os.path.exists("../html/Rohith/"):
    os.makedirs("../html/Rohith/")
jsonObj = json.dumps(mainfunc(s))
fileobj = open("../html/Rohith/data.json","w+")
fileobj.write(jsonObj)
```

Comment: You cant directly write json data into file you have to convert it into string json data is a dict

Comment: But I can create in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guy sitting next to me! It works when I change path as a local destination rather than like IP path:

```
fileobj = open("/var/www/html/Rohith/data.json","w+");
```